# Unity / Vuforia download new imageTargets directly to device

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, 3d, vuforia

I am trying to track an image target rendered by vuforia. I would like to set up a web app where I can upload a new image target that will be downloaded and integrated automatically by the app.

Can I set a folder from which I automatically can use all existing image targets to track?

Answer (score 1):

Well for using image targets different than vuforia provided you have to create your own [database](https://developer.vuforia.com/targetmanager/project/checkDeviceProjectsCreated).
You add a new database than add targets to it. You have to be careful with the ratings of  your images. Then you can download this database as a unitypackage and you can see it has two image targets and .dat and .xml file in it:

## [image]

Then you can use this database using `ImageTargetBehavior`. This database can be your folder where you want to use existing image targets to track.

[image]

Comment: can i automize the selection of the newest image in the code somehow?

Comment: Well you can not access Image Target field and change it in the script if that is what you are asking. Some work around might be creating image targets for all your images and activating new one deactivating old ones. You can also do it [dynamically](https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Solution/How-To-Access-and-Modify-Targets-at-Run-Time.html) in Vuforia. That would be a more robust solution.