# Taking target image from camera using Vuforia

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I have an idea to make an AR android app  using Vuforia and Unity3d with Android Studio. I have never worked with Vuforia so i don't know if it is possible or not.

Basically in app user can set target for Vuforia through mobile camera and he can also assign which object is displayed on that target. For example user takes a picture of a glass as a target and he also sets a video of how glass is made (from uploading or through youtube link). And then video is augmented on glass target.

i don't know if its possible? and how?
any tutorials and guidance would be appreciated.

thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to track an image target you have to create database in your case a user defined one. And this database should be created using [Target Manager](https://developer.vuforia.com/targetmanager/project/checkDeviceProjectsCreated) from Vuforia webpage. Then you have to download this database and add it to your Unity project like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53164618/unity-vuforia-download-new-imagetargets-directly-to-device/53169403#53169403). Therefore, I do not think you can create image targets while your game is running.